# Moving a projectile without recoil?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was thinking that if you have a shaft pushing a projectile you would have to have some sort of recoil along the shaft.  Newton's 3rd law, every action has an equal and opposite reaction.  However, I came up with a thought experiment which doesn't appear to have any recoil.

Imagine a shaft in space, so no gravity, no air.  In the shaft there are vents along its wall that can emit particles perpendicular to the shaft's wall.  The projectile is at rest and then particles from the vents are emitted in a sequential order and with symmetric force on all sides of the projectile such that they hit an area on the projectile that deflects the particles downward.  This would impart momentum on the projectile to go "up".  Yet, there is no recoil, no backward force on the shaft.  The shaft doesn't move, only the emitted particles.  Here's an example image:
[image]
Now my question is, does this make sense?  Is there something that I'm missing?  I'm finding it difficult to believe that one can move a projectile without imparting any net force on the thing that is causing the movement.  Can this be done with a field?  Like magnetism?  Or other mechanism?

Comment: If you consider the high-velocity particles are causing the movement (rather than the shaft), does that make any difference in your question?

Comment: @BowlOfRed, I was wondering if maybe some other means other than particles can also push a projectile forward without recoil, like magnetism.  But I don't think that's the case.

Comment: While the shaft itself might not move up and down, it is now subjected to forces causing it's expansion away from the acis

Comment: Much of the KE would be wasted accelerating the particles backwards

Comment: @Triatticus acis?

Comment: @AdrianHoward, "Much of the KE would be wasted", are you saying that the projectile will have no forward momentum imparted to it?  Because, then the KE would be wasted.

Comment: @Adrian It would have some forward momentum, if the bottom of the launch tube were closed, the pressure build up under the projectile would be greater. It would be more efficient, with greater recoil. But per action and reaction, equal recoil of some form is unavoidable.

Comment: @AdrianHoward, yes, you could "improve" imparting the projectile with more momentum by transferring the momentum of the shaft (and everything that the shaft is attached to) to it, but that isn't what the question was about.  This thought experiment was to see if recoil on the shaft is avoidable, which apparently it is.  "Waste" is a matter of intention.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, with the propellant particles pushed out the back, the projectile and the tube would both move forward with different speeds.

Comment: @Adrian not sure why it wrote that but it should say axis

Comment: @AdrianHoward, why would the tube be pushed forward?  There is no force being applied to the tube except radially towards it's centre.  The projectile is deflecting the particles backward, pushing it forward.  The tube has no other forces acting on it.

Comment: @Triatticus, then I still don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projectile exerts an equal and opposite force on the particles, rather than the shaft, as an impulse is needed to change the motion of said particles. Newton's laws are not violated.

Electric, magnetic and gravitational fields all conserve momentum (because their lagrangians are invariant under translations in space) so Newton's third law cannot be violated using any of these fields. For example, if a projectile is accelerated using an electric field, the charged object causing the field will accelerate in the opposite direction.